# URL doesn't work after removing # from URL Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I'm new in angular i got stuck in below code

i'm using ngRoute for routing, I want to make SEO friendly URL's so that's why i have used below code to remove hash from URL

index.html

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
<li ng-class="{active: isActive('/')}" ><a   href="#">Home</a></li>
<li ng-class="{active: isActive('/faq')}" ><a  href="#faq">FAQ</a>    </li>
<li ng-class="{active: isActive('/content')}" ><a  href="#content">Contents</a></li>
<li ng-class="{active: isActive('/contact')}" ><a   href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
```

in head section added below code

```
<base href="/my_stuff/angular_js/NewSinglePageApp/"></base>
```

.htaccess added

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI}  !^(/index\.php|/img|/js|/css|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule     ./index.html [L]
```

In controller i have added

// configure our routes
    WebApp.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);


    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'index.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })


        .when('/faq', {
            templateUrl : 'faq.html',
            controller  : 'faqController'
        })



        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/data', {
            templateUrl : 'data.html',
            controller  : 'dataController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'contact.html',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        });
});
```

It's working fine while navigation but doesn't work when we try to reload the page or press enter in URL address bar.

Please help me.. thanks in advance

Comment: Did you leave index.html as it is in the question? What are you doing and what happens, precisely?

Comment: it works fine for all the clicks e,g faq, contents, contact and home . but when we refresh the page "http://localhost/my_stuff/angular_js/NewSinglePageApp/faq"  then it gives "page not found error"

Comment: try this - `<a  href="/faq">` (a slash instead of a hash)

Comment: tried same but not working

Comment: can you reproduse the error in a plnkr or jsbin? are there any errors in the console?

Comment: its giving me server side error not javascript error.   I m getting below error'                                                                                         Not Found

The requested URL /my_stuff/angular_js/NewSinglePageApp/faq was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: Hey.... i am facing the same issue.... did you find anywork around for it?